# Instagram API not displaying title and hyperlink

Tags: jquery, instagram

I have created an Instagram request using location lat/lon parameters via jQuery.  I am returning all associated thumbnails, up to count 100, along with:

1. Title = caption, if caption is not null (on mouseover)
2. User who posted image.
3. Date image posted.
4. Hyperlink of standard_resolution.url (upon click on thumbnail)

The below request returns the thumbnail images, user, and date posted.  However, the title/caption and hyperlink to stardard_resolution.url do not display upon mouseover and click.

I believe my append statement syntax is wrong, but can't figure it out.  Here's the code and   [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nbibe/LnJ8T/)

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {


    var count = "100";
    var access_token = "<REMOVED BY CATSHOES - IS THIS SUPPOSED TO BE SECRET?>";
    var access_parameters = {
        access_token: access_token
    };

    function grabImages(access_parameters) {
        var instagramUrl = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=19.951204000000&lng=-155.860291000000&name=xxx&distance=400&callback=?&count=" + count;


        $.getJSON(instagramUrl, access_parameters, onDataLoaded);
    }

    function onDataLoaded(instagram_data) {
        if (instagram_data.meta.code == 200) {
            var photos = instagram_data.data;
            if (photos.length > 0) {
                for (var key in photos) {
                    var photo = photos[key];
                    var a_href = photo.images.standard_resolution.url;
                    var img_title = "";
                    var date = new Date(parseInt(photo.created_time) * 1000);

                    if (photo.caption != null) {
                        img_title = photo.caption.text;
                    }


                    $("#target").append('<a class="preview" href="' + a_href + "'  title='" + img_title + '" ></a> <img src ="' + photo.images.thumbnail.url + '"><div>\
                            ' + "Posted by: ", photo.user.full_name + '<br />\
                            ' + "Posted on: ", (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + '<br />\
                        </div />');
                }

            } else {
                $("#target").append("Currently no Instagram photos for this location.");
            }

        } else {
            var error = data.meta.error_message;
            $("#target").append('Photos for this location will display soon.  Instagram message: ' + error);
        }
    }
    grabImages(access_parameters);

});

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of little mistakes in HTML, the img tag is not within anchor tag, so image is not linked, and the img "src" end quotes and "title" start quotes are incorrect. Works fine if you make this change:

```
$("#target").append('<a class="preview" href="' + a_href + '"  title="' + img_title + '" > <img src ="' + photo.images.thumbnail.url + '"></a><div>\
                            ' + "Posted by: ", photo.user.full_name + '<br />\
                            ' + "Posted on: ", (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + '<br />\
                        </div />');
```

Here is updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LnJ8T/7/), mouseover image works.

Comment: Sorry for not circling back.  Yes, your edits fixed my issue.  Thanks!